# Split date in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, dataframe

In excel file I have columns "date" which contains dates in the following format:
**11/17/2017 2:40:40 PM** this translates to **month/day/year H:M:S**

When importing this file in Pandas its dtype is `<M8[ns]`

So, I want to split the values. Desired output have to be 11/17/2017 and it has to be in the same format as it would be if we do this split in excel file. I mean, I need the values to be like 11/17/2017 but format this date to show only day and month like this:`17-Nov`

I tried several methods but didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So do you need `datetime`s in format `11/17/2017` and not strings?

Comment: Or need `df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b')` ?

Comment: yes, I need datetime in format 11/17/2017 and not string. Output values have to datetime format not string

Comment: sorry, I need second but in datetime format

Comment: If need `17-Nov` in datetime it is not possible.

Comment: I checked and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) because if need `17-Nov` as datetime it is not possible in python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['11/17/2017 2:40:40 PM','11/17/2017 2:40:40 PM'])})
print (df)
                 date
0 2017-11-17 14:40:40
1 2017-11-17 14:40:40

print (df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
0    17/11/2017
1    17/11/2017
Name: date, dtype: object

print (df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b'))
0    17-Nov
1    17-Nov
Name: date, dtype: object
```